# Problema com palavras acentuadas vindas da base de dados MySql

Tags: php, mysql, acentuação, moodle

Estou usando esta consulta pra mostrar dados vindo de um banco de dados moodle, mas as palavras que possuem acentos são mostrados com uma interrogação, já utilizei dois tipos de charset `utf-8` e `ISO-8859-1` mas o erro continua, segue imagem e código:

> IMAGEM

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> CÓDIGO DE CONSULTA

```
<?php
// definições de host, database, usuário e senha
$host = "localhost";
$db   = "bitnami_moodle";
$user = "root";
$pass = "";
// conecta ao banco de dados
$con = mysql_pconnect($host, $user, $pass) or trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR); 
// seleciona a base de dados em que vamos trabalhar
mysql_select_db($db, $con);
// cria a instrução SQL que vai selecionar os dados
$query = sprintf("SELECT name, questiontext FROM mdl_question");
// executa a query
$dados = mysql_query($query, $con) or die(mysql_error());
// transforma os dados em um array
$linha = mysql_fetch_assoc($dados);
// calcula quantos dados retornaram
$total = mysql_num_rows($dados);
?>

<html>

    <head>

    <title>Exemplo</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php

    // se o número de resultados for maior que zero, mostra os dados
    if($total > 0) {
        // inicia o loop que vai mostrar todos os dados
        do {
?>
            <p><?=$linha['name']?> </p> <?=$linha['questiontext']?></p>
<?php
        // finaliza o loop que vai mostrar os dados
        }while($linha = mysql_fetch_assoc($dados));
    // fim do if 
    }
?>
</body>
</html>
<?php
// tira o resultado da busca da memória
mysql_free_result($dados);
?>
```

Comment: Tenta inserir no começo da página.
`<?php header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8"); ?>`

Comment: As palavras no banco estão acentuadas corretamente ou estão sendo salvas com caracteres especiais?

Comment: @ThiagoMagalhães No banco estão acentuadas corretamente

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No seu arquivo de conexão, faça isso:

Modo orientado a objeto:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("host", "user," "senha", "db");

$mysqli->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
$mysqli->query('SET character_set_connection=utf8');
$mysqli->query('SET character_set_client=utf8');
$mysqli->query('SET character_set_results=utf8');
```

Procedural:

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'", $con);
mysql_query('SET character_set_connection=utf8', $con);
mysql_query('SET character_set_client=utf8', $con);
mysql_query('SET character_set_results=utf8', $con);
```

Isso forçará o utf-8 em todos os casos, tanto em envios quanto em respostas.

Você está usando o **mysql**, já é uma tecnologia depreciada, recomendo que dê uma olhada em **mysqli** como fiz no exemplo orientado a objeto.

Comment: Poderia dizer como ficaria em meu código acima?

Comment: Ah sim, vc colocou a parte de conexão, vou colocar aqui, só um momento

Comment: @MiguelSilva dê uma olhada agora

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente!

Comment: @MiguelSilva De nada parceiro ;)

Answer (score 0):

Você tem que utilizar os caracteres em utf8, dizendo assim que os caracteres contidos nas buscas abrangem a totalidade dos simbolos ocidentais.

```
<?php header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8"); ?>
```

coloque isso no começo da pagina ou no conect.